# How to design a filter framework for an application?

Tags: java, sql, database-design, filter, application-design

I'm developing an application that allows to analyze data from different viewpoints. This data is stored in 30+ tables of a SQL database (some tables have a 1:n or n:m relationship).

Now I want to filter this data by different criteria and display the filtered data in my application.

Simplified examples for such filters would be:

> Show all products **IN category X AND Y** which **AT LEAST 100 customers from New York** have bought
>
> Show all customers that have bought a product **with a name starting with 'ab'** and **a price between 100 and 300 USD**

Now I want to provide a filter in my application (similar to ebay where you can filter by category, seller, price, etc.).

**My Question:**

How do I design such a filter framework?

I don't want to write an SQL Query for each possible combination of filters. Additionally, there are at least 10 subjects I want to query and filter and performance is important.

Is there a best practice on how to build such a filter framework?

Comment: How many filters are we talking about? Google the term catch-all queries.

Comment: If you have to ask, you're not ready to build a filter framework.  You use the filter information to dynamically build your SQL.  Just taking your first sentence, you have to get the product, category, and customer tables as well as the information provided, and do a 3 table join.